# Python delete the large file's beginning line

Tags: python, large-files

i have a large file, everytime write a line into file, first check file size, if size reache the limit, delete the beginning of the line. and insert at the ending.who can help me?

anyone else?help me.

Comment: What is your particular problem?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to bring it to you, but that is inappropriate architectual decision.

The issue is hidden deep in file system, rather than Python. In order to delete a first line in a file, you actually have to read whole file and then write it wholly (except first line) back on a storage drive, highly inefficient.

The python code doing this would look something like this:

```
with open('file_path', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

with open('file_path', 'w') as f:
    for item in lines[1:]:
        thefile.write("%s\n" % item)
```

If you tell us what exactly you are trying to achieve, we might come up with a better solution.

For instance, if it is a log file, the solution often used in software is files rotation. I.e, once a log_file1 reached its capacity, it starts writing into log_file2, then log_file3, then log_fileN, and then back into log_file1.. Where N is the maximum amount of files you want to have.

Comment: yes,it is a log file.file can not exceed 1G.only one file.

Comment: thanks ,everybody else?